# Android studio emulator can not be created

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I am using Ubunty Linux. In my android studio, emulator can not  be created. Whenever I try to create it, I got this dialogue box

> An error occurred while creating the AVD. See idea.log for details.

I cannot find idea.log.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in creating AVD in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47142959/error-in-creating-avd-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

You either haven't selected a CPU/ABI target in the dropdown below the target, or you haven't installed a system image. Open your SDK manager and ensure that you've installed ARM EABI v7a System Image

Comment: I have ARM 64 v8a System Image and Google APIs Intel x86 atom System Image installed, aren't they enough?Why do I need ARM EABI v7a System Image either?

Comment: I'm done with ARM EABI v7a System Image............but it's still not working.......!!!