# Error in creating AVD in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am new to android studio.
my problem is when i try to create AVD its showing

> unknown error. see idea.log for details.

I am working on windows8.

[image: Screenshot of AVD]

Comment: To create AVD, you need to have VT-x or virtualisation enabled in your BIOS. Have you done that? See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39542859/3647180

Answer (score 2):

Delete all the files and folder from a directory home//.android/avd It's for Ubuntu. In Windows it's also in the user's folder (.android/avd).

Comment: You need to explain why your answer is correct. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Hi ! I am sorry. I don't know the exact answer of the solution but when i do faced such error, i always solve the issue same way and that's works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Before you create the new Virtual Device, Try downloading via SDK Manager the API level you want on the Virtual Device. This should do it.